# SpeechRecognizer throws onError on the first listening

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech

In the Android 5 I faced with strange problem. The first call to the `startListening` of SpeechRecognizer results to the onError with error code 7 (**ERROR_NO_MATCH**).

I made test app with the following code:

```
if (speechRecognizer == null) {

    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError " + i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResults");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEvent");
        }
    });
}

final Intent sttIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en");
sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");

speechRecognizer.startListening(sttIntent);
```

And have this log messages after first `startListening` call:

```
onError 7
onReadyForSpeech
onBeginningOfSpeech
onEndOfSpeech
onResults
```

And following messages after another `startListening` calls:

```
onRmsChanged
...
onRmsChanged
onReadyForSpeech
onRmsChanged
...
onRmsChanged
onBeginningOfSpeech
onRmsChanged
...
onRmsChanged
onEndOfSpeech
onRmsChanged
onRmsChanged
onRmsChanged
onResults
```

So, what is the reason of this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Might be a bug in the SpeechRecognizer implementation that you are using. Which implementation is it? E.g. I'm seeing something similar with Google App 4.7.13.19.arm.

Comment: Yes, @Kaarel, the problem is on the version 4.7.13.19.arm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem but I couldn't find a workaround, so I ended up just calling return inside onError if the time between startListening and onError is unreasonably short.

```
protected long mSpeechRecognizerStartListeningTime = 0;

protected synchronized void speechRecognizerStartListening(Intent intent) {
    if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
        this.mSpeechRecognizerStartListeningTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RLog.d(this, "speechRecognizerStartListening");
        this.mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
    }
}
...
@Override
public synchronized void onError(int error) {
    RLog.i(this, this.hashCode() + " - onError:" + error);

// Sometime onError will get called after onResults so we keep a boolean to ignore error also
    if (mSuccess) {
        RLog.w(this, "Already success, ignoring error");
        return;
    }

    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - mSpeechRecognizerStartListeningTime;
    if (duration < 500 && error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH) {
        RLog.w(this, "Doesn't seem like the system tried to listen at all. duration = " + duration + "ms. This might be a bug with onError and startListening methods of SpeechRecognizer");
        RLog.w(this, "Going to ignore the error");
        return;
    }

// -- actual error handing code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Seems, it is the only option... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

As soon as you configure the "Okay Google" function to every screen the error appears.

So this seems to be the reason!

Deactivate the function and the problem should be solved

Comment: Confirmed, this seems to be the cause on my devices too. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179293

Answer (score 6):

Done one workaround.

This is a regular flow

onReadyForSpeech -->onBeginningOfSpeech-->onEndOfSpeech -->onResults

But weired flow

onError(no match) -->onReadyForSpeech -->onBeginningOfSpeech-->onEndOfSpeech  -->onResults

So set a boolean on the end of speech to true. and check onError to make sure that it has thrown an error after an end of speech!

```
speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
isEndOfSpeech = false;

 @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        if (!isEndOfSpeech)
            return;
}


 @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() { 
        isEndOfSpeech = true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on several devices. It seems onError(7) is always called before onReadyForSpeech(), so if to avoid using ugly times, you can do something like:

```
public void start(){
    performingSpeechSetup = true;
    speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
}
```

and in the RecognitionListener:

```
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {
    performingSpeechSetup = false;
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {
    if (performingSpeechSetup && error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH) return;
    // else handle error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be very easy in my case. The launching sound of the voice recognition was too loud and triggered the listening process at the very beginning. Turn down the system sound would help. (The volume key)