# Android SpeechRecognizer fails on second listen

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech

I am having an issue where the SpeechRecognizer will listen correctly, and when I get it to go to SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH the next time I listen the recognizer instantly fails to SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH.  The third time i listen will work again.  Any ideas?  Code below:  Also, works perfectly when the error code is SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT, will listen correctly on 2nd time.

```
@Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        switch (error) {
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                showLog("ERROR_AUDIO");
                endTimer();
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                showLog("ERROR_CLIENT");
                endTimer();
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                showLog("ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY");
                endTimer();
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                showLog("ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS");
                endTimer();
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                showLog("ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT");
                endTimer();
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                sr.destroy();
                showLog("ERROR_NETWORK");
                endTimer();
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                showLog("ERROR_SERVER");
                endTimer();
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                showLog("ERROR_NO_MATCH");
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                showLog("ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT");
                break;
            default:
                assert false;
                return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in "Google App", uninstall updates to Google app and it will clear the problem or do as this answer
[SpeechRecognizer throws onError on the first listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071650/speechrecognizer-throws-onerror-on-the-first-listening)

Comment: Appreciate the answer

Answer (score -1):

Try to first cancel the recognizer that cause the error, and then start listening again.

```
public void onError(int error) {
    // put this where the bug occurs
    recognizer.cancel();
    recognizer.startListening(yourIntent);
}
```

I found that it helped with a lot of bugs caused by error.

Comment: This is a really bad suggestion. Doing that will cause the recognizer to continue to restart if and error occurs, such as ERROR_NETWORK. Basically causing a constant loop on the UI thread.