# Android Marshmallow 6.0.1 broke my continuous speech recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am creating an application that I am using continuous speech recognition on. It was working great until the other day when I updated my phone to Android 6.0.1, so I am assuming this is what broke the code. Now, almost instantly the speech recognizer throws an ERROR_NO_MATCH error and is only listening for input for less than a second before restarting when it is supposed to listen for 5 seconds. It is causing it to be very hard to say a command to the application. Here is my code:

```
private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    if(sr != null) {
        sr.destroy();
    }
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    sr.setRecognitionListener(this);
    intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    // Start the activity, the intent will be populated with the speech text
    sr.startListening(intent);
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {
    displaySpeechRecognizer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. Seems like the issue might be related to the "always on" behavior change to the "Ok, Google" feature. [SpeechRecognizer throws onError on the first listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071650/speechrecognizer-throws-onerror-on-the-first-listening/31346373#31346373)